# styled-components change theme dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

Is there a way to make `styled-components` theme adjustable on the fly? For instance, I want the user to be able to change the theme from within the UI and also get theme settings from the API on login.
Currently, my theme looks as follows but I would like to change the hardcoded data for variables that I'd be able to set from UI

```
import { DefaultTheme } from 'styled-components'

export const theme: DefaultTheme = {
  backgroundGradient: 'linear-gradient(to bottom, #f8089c, #e87030)',
  palette: {
    white: '#fff',
    error: '#fa0e15',
    pink: '#fe0582',
  },
  text: {
    main: '#f8089c',
    white: '#fff',
    black: '#000',
  },

  breakpoints: {
    xs: '0px',
    sm: '600px',
    md: '960px',
    lg: '1280px',
    xl: '1920px',
  },
}
```

Comment: You can use `input-toggler` in combination with `state` or use `context-api`

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you want your theme to be stored in a `state` somewhere such that it can be updated and those updates will trigger re-renders.

We can use two separate context providers: the [styled-components `ThemeProvider`](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming) and our own context which will provide some sort of callback which is used to update the theme state.

Here's some sample code which should point you in the right direction.

We create a `Context` for the theme update function.  We give it a default value which logs an error.

```
const ThemeUpdateContext = createContext(
  (theme: DefaultTheme) => console.error("attempted to set theme outside of a ThemeUpdateContext.Provider")
)
```

We make a custom theme provider that stores the theme in local state.  This wraps its `children` in providers for both the theme and the update function.

```
export const MyThemeProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  // store the entire theme as state, using your constant as the initial state
  const [myTheme, setMyTheme] = useState(theme);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
      <ThemeUpdateContext.Provider value={setMyTheme}>
        {children}
      </ThemeUpdateContext.Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

We can then use those contexts to make updates from any component inside the `MyThemeProvider`.  You can, for example, push changes to the theme based on a value retrieved from the API or a cookie from `localStorage`.

Here's a very arbitrary example:

```
const SampleComponent = () => {
  const updateTheme = useContext(ThemeUpdateContext);
  const currentTheme = useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => updateTheme({
        ...currentTheme,
        text: {
          ...currentTheme.text,
          main: 'blue',
        }
      })}
    >
      Make Main Text Blue
    </button>
  )
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/QmbLow)